# how to test if XML = '' in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, optimization, xml, query-performance

I am working with sql server 2005 and I had a situation where many values can be passed in a parameter.

Based on this: [Passing multiple values for one SQL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624398/passing-multiple-values-for-one-sql-parameter) this procedure  uses XML as a parameter.

here is the code of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DENORMV2].[udpProductBulletPointSelectByTier1NoteTypeCode] (  
    @Tier1 VARCHAR(10),  
    @LanguageID INT,  
    @SeasonItemID VARCHAR(5) = NULL,
    @ListNoteTypeCode XML,  
    @CacheDuration INT OUTPUT )  
    WITH EXECUTE AS 'webUserWithRW'  
AS

        SELECT  pbp.Tier1, pbp.LanguageId, pbp.NoteText, pbp.NoteTypeCode,  
                pbp.NoteGroup, pbp.SortOrder  
        FROM    dbo.ProductBulletPoint pbp  

        WHERE   Tier1 = @Tier1 
          AND   LanguageId = @LanguageID 
          AND   (      SeasonItemId = @SeasonItemID  
                  OR
                       @SeasonItemID is null
                )

          AND pbp.NoteTypeCode IN (

                 SELECT  NoteTypeCode=BulletPoint.NoteTypeCode.value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(50)')
                   FROM  @ListNoteTypeCode.nodes('/BulletPoint/NoteTypeCode') AS BulletPoint ( NoteTypeCode )

          )

SELECT  @CacheDuration = Duration  
FROM    dbo.CacheDuration  
WHERE   [Key] = 'Product'
GO
```

more info about this procedure [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145329/improving-performance-how-to-pass-a-table-as-parameter-in-sql-server-2005)

this is an example of how it can be called:

```
declare @p5 int  set @p5=86400 
exec DenormV2.udpProductBulletPointSelectByTier1NoteTypeCode
@Tier1=N'WW099',
@LanguageID=3,
@SeasonItemID=N'16AUT',
@ListNoteTypeCode=N'<BulletPoint><NoteTypeCode>GarmentComposition</NoteTypeCode><NoteTypeCode>FootwearAccessoryComposition</NoteTypeCode></BulletPoint>',
@CacheDuration=@p5 output  select @p5
```

Question:

what is the best way to find out whether or not the parameter `@ListNoteTypeCode XML` is empty?

what if they call this procedure like this:

```
declare @p5 int  set @p5=86400 
exec DenormV2.udpProductBulletPointSelectByTier1NoteTypeCode
@Tier1=N'WW099',
@LanguageID=3,
@SeasonItemID=N'16AUT',
@ListNoteTypeCode=N'',
@CacheDuration=@p5 output  select @p5
```

as it was suggested [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145329/improving-performance-how-to-pass-a-table-as-parameter-in-sql-server-2005) I could avoid the select altogether by testing the parameter `@ListNoteTypeCode`.

My main goal in this scenario is to retrieve the data in the best possible performance, since this procedure is not cached in the web-servers and is called over a million times a day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may check for `NULL` and nodes absence (`exist` method of `xml` type):

```
@ListNoteTypeCode is NULL OR @ListNoteTypeCode.exist('*') = 0
```

Your XPath can be more specific, if necessary:

```
@ListNoteTypeCode is NULL OR @ListNoteTypeCode.exist('/BulletPoint/NoteTypeCode/text()') = 0
```

Comment: @marcellomiorelli The check itself may help execute procedure faster in case, when it happen that provided `xml` instance is empty. In such case SqlServer will not spend resources to subsequent `select` statement compilation (or possible recompilation) and execution, instead "empty" select statement can be executed (which is much simpler) as suggested in answer to one of the previous questions.

Comment: @marcellomiorelli Regarding the `'*'` vs `'/BulletPoint/NoteTypeCode/text()'`. It is matter of semantics primarily. If given `xml` instance can not contain nodes other than specified, then checking just `'*'` may be sufficient. However, if provided `xml` instance can contain nodes other than specified, and you use only part of this `xml` instance then you should be more specific in your XPath to test whether given `xml` is _empty for the purpose of this stored proc_.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to test for an empty XML parameter, variable, or column is to check the `DATALENGTH`. Any empty XML item should be 5 bytes. For example:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (XmlParam XML NULL);
INSERT INTO @Test ([XmlParam]) VALUES (NULL), (N''), (N'g');

SELECT t.[XmlParam],
       DATALENGTH(t.[XmlParam]) AS [DATALENGTH],
       CASE (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(t.[XmlParam]), 5))
          WHEN 5 THEN 'EMPTY'
          ELSE 'Not Empty'
       END AS [IsEmpty]
FROM   @Test t;
```

Returns:

```
XmlParam     DATALENGTH    IsEmpty
--------     ----------    ---------
NULL         NULL          EMPTY
             5             EMPTY
g            9             Not Empty
```

Please note that I used `ISNULL(DATALENGTH(t.[XmlParam]), 5)` as that should be fine for checking a parameter or variable. If checking a column, it might be better to use `XmlColumn IS NULL OR DATALENGTH(XmlColumn) = 5`.

Please also note that while it is *possible* for the internal representation of XML data to change between versions, I have tested on SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012, and 2014 and the size of an empty XML item is consistently 5.

Comment: @marcellomiorelli My gut feeling is that checking `DATALENGTH` would be faster than invoking the XML parser, BUT I have not tested it. However, it should be easy to test by generating a result set of 1 million rows (CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns) and include my version and then remove that and run again with i-one's version. Please post the results.

Comment: I have posted the results of the comparison [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147329/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-check-whether-a-xml-column-is-empty-xml-in) Please have a look when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

My XML uses Schema.
`DATALENGTH` will *definitely* not work.
Even with no Data, you will still have Schema taking up random amounts of space.

This will test for Missing Elements/Nodes (works with *or* without Schema):

```
SELECT ISNULL(@ListNoteTypeCode.exist('*:BulletPoint/*:NoteTypeCode'), 0)[HasRows]
```

With that out of the way, the purpose of your question was to improve performance.
You are using a Correlated-SubQuery!  **:O**
Yikes!  Move that into an Table-Variable with a PK on `NoteTypeCode`.
Then Inner-Join to your Table-Variable and forget about all this *Test-For-Missing-Xml* business.