# Where to find the size of SQL Server data types?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, datatypes, xml

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166025/where-to-find-the-size-of-sql-server-data-types) but none of the answers was really helpful in finding out the size for example, of a XML variable.

```
declare @myVariable XML
```

I have learned from this question:
[how to test if XML = '' in sql server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147178/how-to-test-if-xml-in-sql-server)

> Please also note that while it is possible for the internal
>   representation of XML data to change between versions, I have tested
>   on SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012, and 2014 and the size of an empty XML
>   item is consistently 5.

How can I find the size of each SQL Server Data Type?

How can I prove that the size of an XML is 5?

all this started when I was tuning a stored procedure and while using XML as a parameter
[improving performance - how to pass a table as parameter in sql server 2005?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145329/improving-performance-how-to-pass-a-table-as-parameter-in-sql-server-2005?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This list looks comprehensive.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

Comment: @ScottHodgin it is helpful but It does not say the size of most of the data types, xml for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I prove that the size of an XML is 5?

I believe this question is better stated as: "Where to find the size of **variable-length** SQL Server data types?"

The issue with variable-length types is that there is no specific size that can be documented anywhere as it all depends on the data currently being stored in a particular variable or column. And the only way to know the current size is to use the [DATALENGTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) built-in function. For example:

```
DECLARE @TestXML XML;
SELECT DATALENGTH(@TestXML);

SET @TestXML = N'';
SELECT DATALENGTH(@TestXML);

SET @TestXML = N'g';
SELECT DATALENGTH(@TestXML);
GO
```

Which returns:

```
NULL
5
9
```

Now, the `XML` datatype does more than just provide convenient access functions for `.value`, `.nodes`, `.query`, and `.exist`. It is "optimized" in that the physical storage is reduced by creating a dictionary of the tag and attribute names and replacing the text with an ID that can be looked up. So the internal representation of an XML document is not what you see when looking at the XML document.

As you can see below, the `NVARCHAR` string is 94 bytes due to being UTF-16 (Little Endian) and having 47 characters (as expected). That same value converted to `VARCHAR` takes up only 47 bytes for those 47 characters (as expected). However, once converted to `XML`, the size in bytes is 53. How is that? Well, the text of the "row" and "col" tags is recorded only once (in the internal dictionary) and then IDs are used in the internal hierarchy of the document.

```sql
DECLARE @TestNVARCHAR NVARCHAR(500);
SET @TestNVARCHAR = N'<row><col>1</col><col>2</col><col>3</col></row>';

SELECT LEN(@TestNVARCHAR) AS [LEN], DATALENGTH(@TestNVARCHAR) AS [DATALENGTH];
-- 47   94

DECLARE @TestVARCHAR VARCHAR(500);
SET @TestVARCHAR = CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), @TestNVARCHAR);

SELECT LEN(@TestVARCHAR) AS [LEN], DATALENGTH(@TestVARCHAR) AS [DATALENGTH];
-- 47   47

DECLARE @TestXMLfromNVARCHAR XML;
SET @TestXMLfromNVARCHAR = CONVERT(XML, @TestNVARCHAR);

SELECT @TestXMLfromNVARCHAR, DATALENGTH(@TestXMLfromNVARCHAR) AS [DATALENGTH];
-- <row><col>1</col><col>2</col><col>3</col></row>  53
```

This is also why white space and formatting is ignored and the format of the `XML` value when selected might not be exactly as it was when it was set / inserted:

```sql
DECLARE @EmptyTag XML;
SET @EmptyTag = N'<test></test>             <test></test>';
SELECT @EmptyTag;
-- <test /><test />
```

There are at least two cases, however, where `DATALENGTH` does not *appear* to be accurate: `SPARSE` data and Data Compression. The `SPARSE` option (introduced in SQL Server 2008) allows fixed-length types to take up 0 bytes when `NULL`, but then their standard size plus 4 bytes when `NOT NULL`. However, that doesn't show up correctly here:

```sql
DECLARE @TestSPARSE TABLE
(
  RowID INT NOT NULL,
  Col1 BIGINT SPARSE NULL,
  Col2 TINYINT SPARSE NULL
);
INSERT INTO @TestSPARSE ([RowID], [Col1], [Col2]) VALUES (1, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO @TestSPARSE ([RowID], [Col1], [Col2]) VALUES (2, NULL, NULL);

SELECT RowID,
       Col1,
       DATALENGTH([Col1]) AS [BytesCol1],
       Col2,
       DATALENGTH([Col2]) AS [BytesCol2]
FROM   @TestSPARSE;
```

Returns:

```sql
RowID    Col1    BytesCol1    Col2    BytesCol2
1        0       8            0       1
2        NULL    NULL         NULL    NULL
```

In cases like these you would need to use `DBCC PAGE` to view the actual row in the actual data page to see what is really happening.

Data Compression behaves the same as the `SPARSE` option in terms of the effect (or lack thereof) on the value reported by `DATALENGTH`. This, I suppose, should make sense given that `DATALENGTH` reports the number of bytes taken up by the *datatype* (which applies to both variables and columns), but the `SPARSE` option and Data Compression are storage optimizations (which only apply to columns).